# Concerned about starting graduate school in Hong Kong

Tags: china, hong-kong, covid-19

I am an international student, supposed to start graduate studies this Fall in Hong Kong, mid August onwards. With the ongoing 2019 novel-CoV (Corona Virus) crisis in Hong Kong, I am getting concerned about what will happen. I have stopped applying to graduate schools since I already got my first priority offer from Hong Kong in early January.

I realize it might be petty in light of the current events in China and the SARs to talk about my graduate studies options when people are getting infected daily in the thousands, but are there any predictions as to whether the Virus will be contained soon? Should I start looking for backups?

Comment: What does your university say? They'll be in contact with your own country's foreign affairs office and their own insurance so they'll be in a better position to judge your plans. For example, our university has cancelled all trips (exchanges / semesters abroad) to China and Hong Kong until the whole of March (and later trips subject to how the situation progresses). Or are you trying to enroll in a full program in Hong Kong (without a connection to a different university at home)?

Comment: I am starting full-time graduate studies (no exchange or study abroad). I expect things will resolve in a couple months hopefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even the most cautious models right now models the virus to be contained towards the end of May.

Give that you then have a few more months until August I would say this is not so much of a worry for you if you are a normal middle age person with no prior heart or respiratory conditions and even so in August the risk should be minimal.

I am currently in the middle of it all in Mainland China, and with common sense and hygiene I am not at all worried about this virus.

Follow the recommendations, do not spend in needed time in public places etc and things are totally fine.

So keep up to date with the news but for August timeframes I would not worry to much.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I feel like I am just panicking. Hopefully things will resolve soon. Stay safe.

Comment: @europa1610 for HK I would not panic, just be careful and keep good personal hygiene you will be fine and like I said by August hopefully things are totally under control

Answer (score 2):

I'm living in Hong Kong and avoiding crowds and being in public places more than necessary. Good hygiene, such as washing you hands regularly and not touching hand rails more than absolutely necessary is good means of prevention. Many companies and Government departments have implemented "Work From Home" policies, reduces the number of people commuting which also helps.

Be aware social media seems to have quite an impact here and there have been some episodes of panic-buying: rice, detergents, tissues including toilet tissue; have sold out in many stores. Face masks are also in short supply and there are signs that profiteering is happening too. I saw a box of face masks for around 300 HKD yesterday (38 USD). I imagine most of this will correct itself before August.